# Git error file does not exist anymore

Tags: git, git-merge

I have tried a git rm, but get the following error - the files are actually deleted.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/CognitoSync/CognitoSyncClient.php
    vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/CognitoSync/Resources/cognitosync-2014-06-30.php
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how do I resolve the error or force it to merge.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did before the error appeared?

Comment: @LeBlaireau git stash always helps in such cases

Comment: Did this occur while resolving a merge conflict?